# What does this error in beautiful soup means?

Tags: python, pyqt, beautifulsoup

I'm doing little script using PyQt4 and BeautifulSoup. Basically you specify url and than script supposed to download all pic's from web-page.

In the output, when I provide http://yahoo.com it downloads all the pictures except one:

```
...
Download Complete
Download Complete
File name is wrong 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./picture_downloader.py", line 41, in loadComplete
    self.download_image()
  File "./picture_downloader.py", line 58, in download_image
    print 'File name is wrong ',image['src']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.7.egg/bs4/element.py", line 879, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'src'
```

output from http://stackoverflow.com is:

```
Download Complete
File name is wrong  h
Download Complete
```

And finally , here is part of the code:

```
# SLOT for loadFinished
def loadComplete(self): 
    self.download_image()

def download_image(self):
    html = unicode(self.frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')
    soup = bs(html)

    for image in soup.findAll('img'):
        try:
            file_name = image['src'].split('/')[-1]
            cur_path = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(cur_path, 'images/')):
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(cur_path, 'images/'))
            f_path = os.path.join(cur_path, 'images/%s' % file_name)
            urlretrieve(image['src'], f_path)
            print "Download Complete"
        except:
            print 'File name is wrong ',image['src']
    print "No more pictures on the page"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that the `image` element doesn't have a `"src"` attribute, and you get the same error twice: once in `file_name = image['src'].split('/')[-1]` and after that in the except block `'File name is wrong ',image['src']`.

---

The simplest way to avoid the problem would be to replace `soup.findAll('img')` with `soup.findAll('img',{"src":True})` so it would only find the elements that have a `src` attribute.

---

If there are two possibilities, try something like:

```
for image in soup.findAll('img'):
    v = image.get('src', image.get('dfr-src'))  # get's "src", else "dfr_src"
                                                # if both are missing - None
    if v is None:
        continue  # continue loop with the next image
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: The error is occurring on `file_name = image['src'].split('/')[-1]`

Comment: @That1Guy -- you are right, fixed it 3 seconds before your comment :P

Comment: @Vor -- to avoid that problem try : `soup.findAll('img',{"src":True})`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm trying to do right now, but the thing, I just checked HTML, and some images instead of plain `src` attribute have `dfr-src=` attribute.

Comment: @Vor -- added another option.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is what's going on. Within your try-except, you're getting a `KeyError` from `file_name = image['src'].split('/')[-1]` because that object does not have a `src` attribute.

Then, after your `except` statement, you're trying to access the same attribute that caused the error: `print 'File name is wrong ',image['src']`.

Examine the `img` tag causing the error and reevaluate your logic for those cases.

Comment: So if I check at the beginning, if img has src attribute, than it should work, right?

Comment: That will resolve the error, but won't download the image. Inspect the element that is causing the error to find another way to download it.