# Python sort to avoid "KeyError: 'href'"

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, beautifulsoup, keyerror

I use code as below to sort links:

```
links = set(soup.findAll('a'))
links = sorted(links, key=lambda x: x['href'], reverse=True)
```

sometime I got error as this:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this error in beautiful soup means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587728/what-does-this-error-in-beautiful-soup-means)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes web designers will include anchors (<a> tags) without href attribute, i.e., anchors that don't link to any URLs. One reason this is useful is so you can refer to sections in the webpage:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a name="first"></a>
        <p>blah</p>
        <a name="second"></a>
        <p>blah2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above, if you go to page#second, the browser will position the anchor with the corresponding name at the top of the page.

To fix your code, you could first filter your links for the existence of the href attribute:

```
links = filter(lambda x: x.has_attr('href'), links)
```

Comment: how can I use that sort above without exception?

Comment: @mikezang I just updated it to actually answer your question. If you want to ignore anchor elements that do not have href attribute, then you can remove those tags before sorting.

Comment: @mikezang What do you want to do with the anchors without `href`?

Comment: @uakfb `links = filter(lambda x: 'href' in x, links)` got nothing.

Comment: @janne-karila remove them if no href.

Comment: @mikezang sorry, I thought it was a dict; I fixed the answer to use has_attr. Aran-Fey's comment on your question has another possibly better solution that adds an argument to findAll call.

Comment: @uakfb thanks a lot, I got it.by the way, If I want to sort tag a, what can I do? `sorted(links)` seems like doesn't work.

Comment: @mikezang What is the issue with your sorted call?